# printing all email addresses of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

given an string containing one or more email addresses,how can I go about writing a function
that prints all valid email addresses of the string.
consider code below which can decide if the string is exactly an email address ,meaning it
can not decide if a string contains an email address.
How can I develop this code, so it will check if a string contains one or more email addresses
and then print them ?

```
import re
def check(email):
      return re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email) != None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use re.findall:

```
emails = re.findall('[^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@ ]+', stringWithEmails)
```

Edit: Well, probably you'll need a better RE for matching e-mails, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address), for example.

Comment: You should probably exclude spaces too.

Comment: @Ingo: Can you explain your statement?

Comment: @Faust because for example this: `"STOP-ESM.org" <info@stop-esm.org>` is a valid E-Mail address.

Comment: No, `info@stop-esm.org` is a valid email address. `"STOP-ESM.org" <info@stop-esm.org>` is a valid content for the `rcpt-to` header. They are slightly different things.